Getting "BadRequest" when trying to deploy web app networking settings using Bicep trmplate
While deploying web app Networking Inbound traffic configuration I want to select the Public Network Access setting as "Select Virtual Networks & IP Addresses" where I will add a private endpoint using another private endpoint module.
It allows me to make change in networking manually but bicep gives me 'BadRequest' error when deploying through pipeline.
resource appPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' existing = {
  name: appPlan
}

resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: webAppName
  location: location
  tags: tags
  kind: 'app'
  identity: 'SystemAssigned'
  properties: {
    reserved: true
    serverFarmId: serverFarm.id
    httpsOnly: true
    vnetRouteAllEnabled: false
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    virtualNetworkSubnetId: subnetid
    siteConfig: {
      alwaysOn: true
      ftpsState: 'Disabled'
      appSettings: AppSettings
    }
  }
}

// Change public access to enabled with specific access
resource webAppNetworkAccess 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: webApp
  name: 'config'
  properties: {
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    ipSecurityRestrictions: [
      {
        ipAddress: '10.0.0.0/19'
        action: 'Allow'
        tag: 'Default'
        priority: 100
        name: 'subnet1'
      }
      {
        ipAddress: '10.0.0.1/19'
        action: 'Allow'
        tag: 'Default'
        priority: 110
        name: 'Subnet2'
      }
      {
        ipAddress: 'Any'
        action: 'Deny'
        priority: 12345678
        name: 'Deny all'
        description: 'Deny all access'
      }
    ]
  }
}


This is what currently is

This is what I want to achieve using bicep



Getting "Bad Request" when trying to deploy web app networking settings using Bicep template:

You need to configure a private endpoint with a specific DNS Zone group and network configuration to achieve the requirement. Use below Bicep code for the clear approach.
var AddressPrefix = '10.0.0.0/16'
var privateDnsZone = 'privatelink${environment().suffixes.Hostname}'
resource appPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-06-01' = {
  name: 'AppServicePlanjah'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
  sku: {
    name: 'P1V2'
  }
  kind: 'linux'
}
resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'abrakjam'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  kind: 'app'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    reserved: true
    serverFarmId: appPlan.id
    httpsOnly: true
    vnetRouteAllEnabled: false
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    siteConfig: {
      alwaysOn: false
      ftpsState: 'Disabled'
    }
  }
}
resource webAppNetworkAccess 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: webApp
  name: 'web'
  properties: {
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    ipSecurityRestrictions: [
      {
        ipAddress: '10.0.0.0/19'
        action: 'Allow'
        tag: 'Default'
        priority: 100
        name: 'AllowSubnet1'
      }
      {
        ipAddress: '10.0.0.1/19'
        action: 'Allow'
        tag: 'Default'
        priority: 110
        name: 'AllowSubnet2'
      }
      {
        ipAddress: 'Any'
        action: 'Deny'
        priority: 200
        name: 'DenyAll'
        description: 'Deny all other access'
      }
    ]
  }
}
resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-05-01' = {
  name: 'sdaskjd'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        AddressPrefix
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource subnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2021-05-01' = {
  parent: vnet
  name: 'askdjlksjd'
  properties: {
    addressPrefix: '10.0.0.0/24'
    privateEndpointNetworkPolicies: 'Disabled'
  }
}

resource privateEndpoint 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints@2022-01-01' = {
  name: 'asjd-privateEndpoint'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    subnet: {
      id: subnet.id
    }
    privateLinkServiceConnections: [
      {
        name: 'plsConnection'
        properties: {
          privateLinkServiceId: webApp.id
          groupIds: ['sites'] 
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource privateDnsZone 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones@2020-06-01' = {
  name: privateDnsZone
  location: 'global'
  properties: {}
  dependsOn: [
    vnet
  ]
}
resource dnsZone 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups@2024-01-01' = {
  parent: privateEndpoint
  name: 'sddnsZoneGroup'
  properties: {
    privateDnsZoneConfigs: [
      {
        name: 'default'
        properties: {
          privateDnsZoneId: privateDnsZone.id
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Output:




I am creating private endpoint and the dns zones as part of another module which will be depending on this web app module. Would it necessarily have to be in the same module?

Have you added depends_on block if it is in another module! @user

yes I had added, actually I found the error, it seems weird but was due to the name what I was giving to this resource - webAppNetworkAccess.

So is the issue solved now! @user
